# Unable to change date format To and From DateRange Amcharts

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, amcharts, amcharts4

I am trying to change the date format of `DateRange` To and From Date I tried a lot but looks like I am missing something or amcharts not providing that kind of format.

Current Format

`YYYY-MM-DD`

Required Format

`DD-MM-YYYY`

JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hassanuos/Lmcphu4f/61/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to [specify a format](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/plugin-range-selector/#Date_time_format_of_the_input_fields) for these inputs: https://jsfiddle.net/1ox7zyde/

```
selector.inputDateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
```